# Column doesn't exist when using WITH statement PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, column-alias

I want to create a function to be used to get the node traversal path.

```
CREATE TYPE IDType AS (id uuid);

drop function F_ItemPath;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_ItemPath (item record)
RETURNS TABLE (item_id uuid, depth numeric)
AS $$
BEGIN
return QUERY
    WITH recursive item_path AS (
        SELECT ic.parent_item_id, depth=1
        from item_combination ic, item i 
        WHERE ic.child_item_id=i.id
        UNION all
        SELECT ic.parent_item_id, depth=ip.depth + 1
        FROM item_path ip, item_combination ic WHERE ip.parent_item_id=ic.child_item_id
        )
        SELECT item_id=ip.parent_item_id, depth=ip.depth FROM item_path ip;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from F_ItemPath(('55D6F516-7D8F-4DF3-A4E5-1E3F505837A1', 'FFE2A4D3-267C-465F-B4B4-C7BB2582F1BC'))
```

there has two problems:

1. I tried using user-defined type to set parameter type `CREATE TYPE IDType AS (id uuid);`, but I don't know how to call the function with table argument
2. there has an error that says:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column ip.depth does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function f_itempath(record) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

what I expected is I can use the function normally and the argument can be supplied from other tables.

this is the full query that you can try:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9caba/1
I made the query in DBEAVER app, it will have some different error message.
I suggest you can experiment with it outside sqlfiddle.

Comment: Just the `WITH.....;` piece of your function returns an error ("ERROR: column "depth" does not exist Position: 68") which you should fix first.   You cannot use a function if the definition of it is incorrect, so "what I expected is I can use the function normally" is ?? 
  see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9caba/18

Answer (score 2):

The expression `depth=1` tests if the column `depth` equals the value 1 and returns a boolean value. But you never give that boolean expression a proper name.

Additionally you can't add numbers to boolean values, so the expression `depth=ip.depth + 1` tries to add `1` to a value of `true` or `false` - which fails obviously. If it did work, it would then compare that value with the value in the column `depth` again.

Did you intend to alias the value `1` with the name `depth`? Then you need to use `1 as depth`  and `ip.depth + 1 as depth`  in the recursive part.

In the final select you have the same error - using boolean expressions instead of a column alias

It's also highly recommended to use explicit JOIN operators which were introduced in the SQL standard over 30 years ago.

Using PL/pgSQL to wrap a SQL query is also a bit of an overkill. A SQL function is enough.

Using an untyped record as a parameter seems highly dubious. It won't allow you to access columns using e.g. `item.id`. But given your example call, it seems you simply want to pass multiple IDs for the anchor (no-recursive) part of the query. That's better done using an array or a varadic parameter which allows listing multiple parameters with commas.

So you probably want something like this:

```
drop function f_itempath;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_itempath(variadic p_root_id uuid[])
  RETURNS TABLE (item_id uuid, depth integer)
as
$$  
  WITH recursive item_path AS (
    SELECT ic.parent_item_id, 1 as depth
    FROM item_combination ic
    WHERE ic.child_item_id = any(p_root_id) --<< no join needed to access the parameter
    UNION all
    SELECT ic.parent_item_id, ip.depth + 1
    FROM item_path ip
       JOIN item_combination ic ON ip.parent_item_id = ic.child_item_id
  )
  SELECT ip.parent_item_id as item_id, ip.depth 
  FROM item_path ip;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then you can call it like this (note: no parentheses around the parameters)

```
select * 
from f_itempath('55d6f516-7d8f-4df3-a4e5-1e3f505837a1', 'ffe2a4d3-267c-465f-b4b4-c7bb2582f1bc');

select * 
from f_itempath('55d6f516-7d8f-4df3-a4e5-1e3f505837a1', 'ffe2a4d3-267c-465f-b4b4-c7bb2582f1bc', 'df366232-f200-4254-bad5-94e11ea35379');

select * 
from f_itempath('55d6f516-7d8f-4df3-a4e5-1e3f505837a1');
```

Comment: I tried using user-defined type to set parameter type "CREATE TYPE IDType AS (id uuid);", but I don't know how to call the function with table argument, can you revise the answer using that type in parameter and demonstrate how to call the function?

Comment: and also when I ran your answer there has an error that says "SQL Error [42P13]: ERROR: VARIADIC parameter must be an array".

Comment: @muazhari: I have already fixed the variadic definition

Comment: Just declare the parameter as `variadic p_root_id idtype[])` then. Why do you create an extra _type_ to encapsulate a `uuid`? That's complete overkill. But If you really want a special data type, a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) would probably be a better choice.

Comment: what if I need to supply the argument from tables? how to implement that?

Comment: Extra columns for what? In the output? Additional parameters? Please do not extend your questions to a completely new topic once you have an answer that solves your initial problem. If you have another question, then [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question

Comment: I mean that function will be used to another query and the argument is supplied from other tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230439/discussion-between-muazhari-and-a-horse-with-no-name).